# Obtener ruta actual de mi script powershell

Tags: powershell

Hola tengo un problema que me esta comiendo la cabeza, a pesar de leer en muchas preguntas similares no doy con la resolucion de mi problema.

Tengo un script powershell con dos linas al comienzo:

```
$currentdirectory = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
cd $currentdirectory

comando 1
comando 2
comando n...
```

esas dos lineas me permite almacenar la ruta donde se ejecuta el script en una variable y después me muevo a esa posición.

Todo bien hasta ahora, mi problema es que si por alguna razon el script esta dentro de una capeta cuyo nombre tenga espacios no me permite ejecutar el script, es decir:

path: C:\User\nameuser\Documents\carpeta con espacios\myscript.ps1

como puedo hacer para que las dos primeras lineas no me interpreten los espacios?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

A mi sí que me funciona así. En cualquier caso, creo que es más sencillo utilizar la variable automática $PsScriptRoot:

$currentdirectory = **$PsScriptRoot**
cd $currentdirectory

comando 1
comando 2
comando n...

Comment: ¿Será posible que nos expliques brevemente que hace la línea `$currentdirectory = $PsScriptRoot cd $currentdirectory` y cómo se compara con la utilizada en la pregunta?